# Upgrading OS from terminal

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

So I already know how to upgrade system packages from terminal with `apt-get` or `synaptic` or `aptitude` but what about upgrading the OS from an older version to a newer release version but from the terminal screen?

I know it can be done through the graphical user interface with Update Manager tool, but I'm interested in how OS upgrades can be performed from terminal.

Comment: @StephenKitt Linux Mint

Comment: why the down vote? give the reason.

Comment: Maybe, because you could have googled it.

Comment: @JodkaLemon Maybe I already did, and I can't see anything relating to my question?

Comment: "linux mint upgrade apt-get" gives me three howtos in the first four links and one discussion about "dist-upgrade vs. upgrade". If this doesn't answer your question, I misunderstood your question. I mean that. Maybe there is a misunderstanding regarding your topic. Happens sometimes. That's why editing is so important.

Comment: "what about upgrading the OS from an older version to a newer release version but from the terminal screen?" any system with APT, can be upgraded just by tweaking the sources.list file and doing dist-upgrade. What is your issue? Why you think apt-get isn't able to do the task you mean to do? Do you know that the update manager use APT in the backend?

Comment: Your question was lacking in important details (e.g. which distribution) and there was no indication of research effort. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: type `man aptitude` and `man apt-get`

Comment: @C3nk7 On this Q&A site you don't have to give a reason for up nor for downvotes. If you hover above the down arrow you get among other reasons for downvotes "does not show research effort" maybe that rings a bell?

Answer (score 5):

You can adapt the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g. from

```
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com qiana main
```

to

```
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela main
```

Then `apt-get update` / `apt-get dist-upgrade` will do the job.

Comment: This is not relevant to what I'm talking about.

Comment: @C3nk7 I am pretty sure, that's exactly the answer to your question.

Comment: @klimpergeist Don't forget `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @Jodka For Debian yes, but the URLs aren't appropriate for Mint.

Comment: @Jodka-Lemon Of course, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @StephenKitt Just details. klimpergeist wrote "e.g."...

Comment: Details that can end up messing up your system (at least according to the [wiki](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2))...

Comment: @JodkaLemon This is not what I'm talking about.

Comment: @StephenKitt Right, that was sloppy. I put in mint repositories instead.

Comment: @StephenKitt I wasn't serious. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

After editing the **sources.list** and doing an `apt-get update` as mentioned in **@klimpergeist's** answer, it is a better practice to do a

`apt-get dist-upgrade --download-only`

and then,

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Why is this better than `apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Good to know. Is the reason that interrupted downloads might break the upgrade process? I would have hoped that `apt-get` is smart enough to circumvent such problems.

Comment: In case of an error in network connection, when using `apt-get dist-upgrade`, the system upgrade will be hindered. Using `apt-get dist-upgrade --download-only`  all the packages are downloaded first, thus the system upgrade can be done later much more smoothly even in the absence of a network connection. @klimpergeist I don't know if `apt-get` could circumvent such problems, but this is more of a personal preference.

Comment: `apt-get` downloads everything before it starts installing anything so I'm not sure this helps...